# How to parse specific JSON data into a string in C language

Tags: c, json, parsing, strtok

I'm currently developing the uptime functionality of my Twitch ChatBot, and i have to deal with the JSON of Twitch API...using just C...with no libraries.

This is the Twitch JSON file that i `curl` from my ChatBot:

```
{
    "stream": {
        "_id": 00000000000,
        "game": "Science \u0026 Technology",
        "viewers": 2,
        "video_height": 720,
        "average_fps": 30,
        "delay": 0,
        "created_at": "2019-02-07T12:31:43Z",
        "is_playlist": false,
        "stream_type": "live",
        "preview": {
            "small": "",
            "medium": "",
            "large": "",
            "template": ""
        },
        "channel": {
            "mature": true,
            "partner": false,
            "status": "[ITA]  Twitch Chatbot in C Language | Just Chilling | Ask Questions",
            "broadcaster_language": "it",
            "broadcaster_software": "",
            "display_name": "St3veR0nix",
            "game": "Science \u0026 Technology",
            "language": "it",
            "_id": 000000000,
            "name": "st3ver0nix",
            "created_at": "2016-04-24T11:03:28Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-07T14:57:54Z",
            "delay": null,
            "logo": "",
            "banner": null,
            "video_banner": null,
            "background": null,
            "profile_banner": "",
            "profile_banner_background_color": "",
            "url": "",
            "views": 1243,
            "followers": 40,
            "_links": {
                "self": "",
                "follows": "",
                "commercial": "",
                "stream_key": "",
                "chat": "",
                "features": "",
                "subscriptions": "",
                "editors": "",
                "teams": "",
                "videos": ""
            }
        },
        "_links": {
            "self": ""
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": "",
        "channel": ""
    }
}
```

The data which i'm looking for is the date when my stream started, so i need the content of the first `"created_at"` tag. Then i can simply `strtok()` the content of that tag and get the actual date in the format hours:minutes:seconds.

For now i tried this solution, but it seems that every time the stream gets updated, the JSON file gets somehow modified with my solution that proves not to be the most correct solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


#define __USE_XOPEN
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER 10000

void Date_Parser(char * buffer, char * output)
{
    char * tok = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER);

    int c;
     for(c = 0, tok = strtok(buffer, "created_at:"); tok != NULL; tok = strtok(NULL, "T"), c++)
    {
        if(c == 3)
        {
              tok = strtok(tok, "Z");
              strcpy(output, tok);
              break;
        }
    }
}

void Find_Time(char * start_date, char * output)
{
    char * return_value = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
    struct tm ttime;

    strptime(start_date, "%H:%M:%S", &ttime);

    time_t start = mktime(&ttime);
    time_t end;
    time(&end);

    time_t seconds = difftime(end, start);
    struct tm * date = localtime(&seconds);

    if(date->tm_hour == 0)
    {
       sprintf(return_value, "%d Hours, %d Minutes, %d Seconds", date->tm_hour, date->tm_min, date->tm_sec); 
    }
    else{
        sprintf(return_value, "%d Hours, %d Minutes, %d Seconds", date->tm_hour-2, date->tm_min, date->tm_sec);
    }
    strcpy(output, return_value);
    return;
}

char * Date_Calculator()
{
    pid_t pid;  
    FILE * fp;
    char * buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER);
    char * time = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*64);

    if((pid = fork()) == -1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nFork Failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        execl("/usr/bin/curl", "curl", "-H","'Authorization: OAuth nm3ht1an41jay1lp98uafkxp1tpsaf'", "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/st3ver0nix?client_id=k9z6dtirx92i34vwkufkzfc4mdekx8", "-omy_api.json", NULL);
    }
    sleep(1);

    if(!(fp = fopen("my_api.json", "r")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nErrore in apertura file api\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int bytes = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), bytes-1, fp);

    char * date = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*128);
    Date_Parser(buffer, date);

    Find_Time(date, time);

    free(date);
    fclose(fp);

    wait(0);
    return time;
}
```

What this code does is: making the request with `curl` and saving the JSON response into a file, trying to parse the data (which proves not to be correct), it takes the actual date to get the difference from the dates, and returns to the main code the time structure converted into a string.

I would like to hear people opinions about this method, and i'm open for any suggestions, but for making this clear, i don't want to use libraries, i want to do it raw.

Comment: Get the source for a library that properly parses JSON.

Comment: @ScottHunter i don't want to use libraries, i want to learn how to do it with C :)

Comment: Read source that does it properly & learn from that.

Comment: Parsing a generic JSON properly is far from trivial. It's close to writing a parser for a full programming-language.

Comment: And if you *really* want to do it yourself, then at least try to avoid memory leaks (like you have quite a few now).

Comment: @ScottHunter ok...i'll look at those source codes, but in the meantime i will look for other code suggestions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah i miss some `free()`

Comment: @xing i'll try that and see if i can arrange better my code

Comment: `strtok(buffer, "created_at:")` this is strange. you tokenize the string with any of the characters from "acertd_" string...

Comment: `execl("/usr/bin/curl",` - if you use `curl` to download the data (as opposed to doing it in C) why don't you just use `sed` or even `jq` for the parsing...

Comment: To do it *right*, you'll want to write a full-up [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).  JSON's [grammar](https://www.json.org/) isn't terribly complicated, but it's going to need something a bit more robust than `strtok`.  I've written my own JSON parser in C++, and it took about a week of solid effort.

Comment: As John says, either you do a crash course on writing a recdescent parser, or you use an existing library. `strtok` is completely inadequate here, it's like attacking a dinosaur with a stick. You're only going to get hurt.

Comment: I've done this once for a product I work on, and writing a (mostly) correct JSON grammar parser including correct string escaping and unescaping that can pull out string:value pairs, (mostly: I don't support values that are objects or arrays (i.e. I support only a subset of JSON until I have time to port a real library like Jannson across all the platforms my product supports)) was just over 500 lines of C with comments.  It was "good enough" for the time window (2 days) I had and subset of JSON I needed to support at the time.